# Matplotlib error: 'height' must be length 5 or scalar

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am attempting to plot the output of the script into a 2 series bar graph using matplotlib in python 2.7.

My script prints 'msg' which results in the following output:

KNN: 90.000000 (0.322734)

LDA: 83.641395 (0.721210)

CART: 92.600996 (0.399870)

NB: 29.214167 (1.743959)

Random Forest: 92.617598 (0.323824)

After the code outputs the results of the 'msg', I attempt to plot the results into a 2 series bar graph using matplotlib and am then returned with the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "comparison.py", line 113, in <module>
    label='mean')
  File "C:\Users\Scot\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2650, in bar
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Scot\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1818, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Scot\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2038, in bar
    "must be length %d or scalar" % nbars)
ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 5 or scalar
```

Im not sure how to fix this, I think it may be due to the values of the results being a float value? Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
# Modules
import pandas
import numpy
import os
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
plt.rcdefaults()
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_curve, average_precision_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind, ttest_ind_from_stats
from scipy.special import stdtr
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import warnings

# Load KDD dataset
data_set = "NSL-KDD/KDDTest+.arff"
import os
os.system("cls")

print "Loading: ", data_set

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

    names = ['duration', 'protocol_type', 'service', 'flag', 'src_bytes', 'dst_bytes', 'land', 'wrong_fragment', 'urgent', 'hot', 'num_failed_logins', 'logged_in', 'num_compromised', 'su_attempted', 'num_root', 'num_file_creations',
             'num_shells', 'num_access_files', 'num_outbound_cmds', 'is_host_login', 'is_guest_login', 'count', 'srv_count', 'serror_rate', 'srv_serror_rate', 'rerror_rate', 'srv_rerror_rate', 'same_srv_rate', 'diff_srv_rate', 'srv_diff_host_rate',
             'dst_host_count', 'dst_host_srv_count', 'dst_host_same_srv_rate', 'dst_host_diff_srv_rate', 'dst_host_same_src_port_rate', 'dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate', 'dst_host_serror_rate', 'dst_host_srv_serror_rate', 'dst_host_rerror_rate', 'class',
             'dst_host_srv_rerror_rate']

    dataset = pandas.read_csv(data_set, names=names)

    for column in dataset.columns:
        if dataset[column].dtype == type(object):
            le = LabelEncoder()
            dataset[column] = le.fit_transform(dataset[column])

    array = dataset.values
    X = array[:, 0:40]
    Y = array[:, 40]

    # Split-out validation dataset
    validation_size = 0.20
    seed = 7
    X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = cross_validation.train_test_split(
        X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)

    # Test options and evaluation metric
    num_folds = 10
    num_instances = len(X_train)
    seed = 10
    scoring = 'accuracy'

    #  Algorithms
    models = []
    models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))  
    models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))  
    models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))  
    models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))  
    models.append(('Random Forest', RandomForestClassifier()))  
    # models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression())) 

    # evaluate each model in turn
    results = []
    names = []
    for name, model in models:
        kfold = cross_validation.KFold(n=num_instances, n_folds=num_folds, random_state=seed)
        cv_results = cross_validation.cross_val_score(
            model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
        results.append(cv_results)
        names.append(name)
        msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean() * 100, cv_results.std()
                               * 100)  # multiplying by 100 to show percentage
        print(msg)
        # print cv_results * 100 # plots all values that make the average

    print ("\n")

    # Perform T Test on each iteration of models.
    for i in range(len(results) - 1):
        for j in range(i, len(results)):
            t, p = ttest_ind(results[i], results[j], equal_var=False)
            print("T_Test between {} & {}: T Value = {}, P Value = {}".format(
                names[i], names[j], t, p))
            print("\n")

    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    n_groups = 5
    # create plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    index = numpy.arange(n_groups)
    bar_width = 0.35
    opacity = 0.8

    rects1 = plt.bar(index, cv_results, bar_width,
                     alpha=opacity,
                     #  color='b',
                     label='mean') # Line 113

    rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, cv_results.std(), bar_width,
                     alpha=opacity,
                     color='g',
                     label='standard_d')

    plt.xlabel('Models')
    plt.ylabel('Percentage')
    plt.title('All Model Performance')
    plt.xticks(index + bar_width, (names))
    plt.legend()

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

printing `cv_results` appears as the following and is 7 or 8 decimal places:

```
[ 90.48146099  90.48146099  89.42999447  89.5960155   90.03873824
  89.9833979   89.9833979   89.76203652  90.09407858  90.14941893]

[ 83.34255672  84.94742667  82.2910902   83.78527947  84.3386829
  83.9513005   82.78915329  84.06198118  83.39789707  83.50857775]

[ 93.1931378   92.69507471  91.92030991  92.52905368  92.69507471
  92.41837299  92.58439402  92.25235196  92.19701162  92.14167128]

[ 29.05368013  26.89540675  31.54399557  28.22357499  29.27504151
  27.94687327  33.20420587  28.99833979  28.55561704  28.44493636]

[ 93.35915883  93.02711677  92.25235196  91.69894853  93.02711677
  92.63973437  92.58439402  92.14167128  92.47371334  92.69507471]
```

Comment: Whats the lenght of `cv_results`?

Comment: @Goyo I have updated the question to show the results of `cv_results`

Comment: I have no idea what kind of object would have that string representation. But if you want the first call to `bar` to plot 5 bars, that doesn't make any sense. You'd better trim your code to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to plot the means of `cv_results`, you need to calculate the means with `.mean()`, as you do with `.std()` in the second plot.

Also, you go through the process of appending `cv_results` for each model to `results`, but then when you come to do the plotting, it seems like you are still using `cv_results`, but this is probably only going to be the cv_results for the last model accessed in the loop.

It looks like your `results` will then be a list containing 5 numpy arrays. So, you could loop over that list, calculate the mean of each array, and use that to plot your barplot:

```
mean_results = [res.mean() for res in results]
rects1 = plt.bar(index, mean_results,  bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 #  color='b',
                 label='mean')
```

Alternatively, you could just append `cv_results.mean()` to a list during your original loop, and use that list to make your bar plot.

Comment: Adding `cv_results.mean()` to a new list worked like a charm! Thanks